# Wifi is disable it is crazy?

Tags: wireless, hp

I am dual booting with Ubuntu 14.10 on my new HP Omen,
but the wifi is not working. The Network Manager says that Wifi is disabled.

I press <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>f12</kbd> to activate it but nothing happens

On terminal I type:

```
sudo rfkill list
```

This results in:

```
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
2: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

I try to unblock all with command

```
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

but get the same output

```
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
2: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

I then tried :

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

I get this:

```
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not possible due to RF-kill
```

`iwconfig` says:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

What do I need to do to enable my Wireless?

Comment: Pleas add the result of `lsmod | grep acer` to the question

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Is the wireless LAN disabled in the BIOS?

Comment: no wireless disable in bios and on windows work

Comment: lsmod | grep acer
acer_wmi               32522  0 
sparse_keymap          13948  2 acer_wmi,hp_wmi
wmi                    19193  4 acer_wmi,hp_wmi,mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  20128  3 i915,acer_wmi,nouveau

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just `sudo modprobe -r acer_wmi` and `sudo rfkill unblock all`
Then to make it permanent `echo "blacklist acer_wmi" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/acer-wmi.conf`

Comment: nothing...                                                           0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
2: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no                                                                network manager now say wifi is disable by hardware switch

Comment: Is there a switch?  Try a reboot

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a Toshiba Satellite laptop running Ubuntu GNOME. I tried different things on the Internet, but could not solve it.

After reading different posts, the solution was to reset the BIOS. Either:

- by removing the CMOS battery or
- by temporary bridging two specific points on the mainboard of the laptop

I did that and the problem was solved.

For detailed view of bridging two specific points, visit the following link to video on YouTube that shows how to reset the BIOS of a Toshiba Satellite laptop.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ihwj_MctVo4

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  **;-)** As videos do not contain any text that is searchable, pure video answers are not allowed here...  Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the video into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always leave the link to the video at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...